# I used the website's URL before using Ajax URL which parsed the table. Now I get "none" when i print

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import requests

import csv

from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

payload = {
    'action': "historical_data",
    'curr_id': "160",
    'st_date' : "01/05/2016",
    'end_date' : "30/05/2016",
    'interval_sec' : "Daily"
}

headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
}

url = 'http://in.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax'

response=requests.post(url,data=payload,headers=headers)

html = response.content

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

print soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'genTbl closedTbl historicalTbl'})
```

Comment: What is the page you are trying to scrape? Provide the URL please.

Comment: http://in.investing.com/currencies/usd-inr-historical-data

Comment: i first used the above url and could parse the table with the above code. But i have assigned a task to get details of table with some date range other than the default range which we get just by loading the page. the table is within the ajax part of webpage. i coludnt get the table.

Comment: if i print the full html code i get the full code of the page except the table's code by giving the ajax url. But i got full code along with the table code with giving the webpage url(http://in.investing.com/currencies/usd-inr-historical-data) not ajax one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off use *bs4*, *BeautifulSoup3* is deprecated and no longer maintained, to fix your issue you need to add another header, *"X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"*:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


payload = {
    'action': "historical_data",
    'curr_id': "160",
    'st_date' : "01/05/2016",
    'end_date' : "30/05/2016",
    'interval_sec' : "Daily"
}
headers = {
        'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0',
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    "X-Requested-With":"XMLHttpRequest"
}
url = 'http://in.investing.com/instruments/HistoricalDataAjax'
response=requests.post(url, data=payload,headers=headers)
html = response.content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"html.parser")
print(soup.find('table', attrs={'class':'genTbl closedTbl historicalTbl'}))
```

Output:

```
<table class="genTbl closedTbl historicalTbl" id="curr_table" tablesorter="">
<thead>
<tr>
<th class="first left noWrap">Date<span class="headerSortDefault" sort_default=""></span></th>
<th class="noWrap">Price<span class="headerSortDefault" sort_default=""></span></th>
<th class="noWrap">Open<span class="headerSortDefault" sort_default=""></span></th>
<th class="noWrap">High<span class="headerSortDefault" sort_default=""></span></th>
<th class="noWrap">Low<span class="headerSortDefault" sort_default=""></span></th>
<th class="noWrap">Change %<span class="headerSortDefault" sort_default=""></span></th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1464566400">May 30, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">67.171</td>
<td>67.030</td>
<td>67.380</td>
<td>67.022</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.21%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1464307200">May 27, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">67.031</td>
<td>66.932</td>
<td>67.135</td>
<td>66.865</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.16%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1464220800">May 26, 2016</td>
<td class="redFont">66.927</td>
<td>67.290</td>
<td>67.415</td>
<td>66.892</td>
<td class="bold redFont">-0.51%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1464134400">May 25, 2016</td>
<td class="redFont">67.273</td>
<td>67.620</td>
<td>67.712</td>
<td>67.213</td>
<td class="bold redFont">-0.53%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1464048000">May 24, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">67.630</td>
<td>67.419</td>
<td>67.780</td>
<td>67.407</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.33%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1463961600">May 23, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">67.409</td>
<td>67.421</td>
<td>67.590</td>
<td>67.233</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.00%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1463702400">May 20, 2016</td>
<td class="redFont">67.408</td>
<td>67.426</td>
<td>67.545</td>
<td>67.310</td>
<td class="bold redFont">-0.04%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1463616000">May 19, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">67.436</td>
<td>67.133</td>
<td>67.610</td>
<td>67.093</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.44%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1463529600">May 18, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">67.140</td>
<td>66.814</td>
<td>67.169</td>
<td>66.814</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.47%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1463443200">May 17, 2016</td>
<td class="redFont">66.825</td>
<td>66.835</td>
<td>66.901</td>
<td>66.665</td>
<td class="bold redFont">-0.03%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1463356800">May 16, 2016</td>
<td class="redFont">66.844</td>
<td>66.915</td>
<td>66.944</td>
<td>66.720</td>
<td class="bold redFont">-0.02%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1463097600">May 13, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">66.855</td>
<td>66.748</td>
<td>66.925</td>
<td>66.710</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.15%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1463011200">May 12, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">66.757</td>
<td>66.551</td>
<td>66.781</td>
<td>66.510</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.29%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1462924800">May 11, 2016</td>
<td class="redFont">66.561</td>
<td>66.621</td>
<td>66.845</td>
<td>66.510</td>
<td class="bold redFont">-0.11%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1462838400">May 10, 2016</td>
<td class="redFont">66.631</td>
<td>66.742</td>
<td>66.786</td>
<td>66.532</td>
<td class="bold redFont">-0.18%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1462752000">May 09, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">66.752</td>
<td>66.591</td>
<td>66.800</td>
<td>66.385</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.23%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1462492800">May 06, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">66.600</td>
<td>66.558</td>
<td>66.715</td>
<td>66.470</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.06%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1462406400">May 05, 2016</td>
<td class="redFont">66.558</td>
<td>66.617</td>
<td>66.675</td>
<td>66.448</td>
<td class="bold redFont">-0.10%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1462320000">May 04, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">66.627</td>
<td>66.569</td>
<td>66.689</td>
<td>66.490</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.10%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1462233600">May 03, 2016</td>
<td class="greenFont">66.558</td>
<td>66.333</td>
<td>66.582</td>
<td>66.225</td>
<td class="bold greenFont">0.32%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="first left bold noWrap" data-real-value="1462147200">May 02, 2016</td>
<td class="redFont">66.347</td>
<td>66.415</td>
<td>66.465</td>
<td>66.310</td>
<td class="bold redFont">-0.12%</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```